# Computer doesnt boot after changing disk partition to GPT

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, mbr, gpt

I have an HP pro 3500 PC with windows 7 installed on it, when I wanted to format it with windows 10 it prompts a message saying "Windows cannot be installed to this disk. the selected disk has an MBR partition table...", I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pb6tECZP6WE and changed all partitions to GPT, but for me the installation didn't want to proceed. So I rebooted the PC and now it doesn't read anything, it just tries to access windows via network.

I did change the order to start from the USB first, and also explicitly told the computer to boot from USB but that didn't work. from my search I found it's a UEFI thing, but I don't really understand what it is.

I'm not really familiar with this sort of issues, I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: You really need a lot of research, patience, work and a bit of luck to solve that. Hope you get your answer very well detailed cause will help me too to learn more about it.

Comment: If you have an option to disable uefi on bios that could be a good start to try another boo t feom usb. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will try it

Comment: Did you `clean` the disk in `diskpart`? Can you see the disk in your bios(uefi)? Did you format your installation USB so it uses GPT instead of MBR?

Comment: Thank you @hextech, It worked after I formatted the USB to use GPT

Comment: I'm glad you solved it - I added an answer below with some more info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on my comment:

MBR (master boot record) is an old type of boot sector which was superseded by GPT (GUID Partition Table). Main advantage of GPT is that it can use more than 4 primary partition and more than 2TB of disk space. I did some tests myself on disk read/write speeds on an SSD - GPT seemed to perform better in most cases, but by less than 2%. Some simply say there are no speed improvements.

As for BIOS and UEFI - no modern computers use BIOS anymore. UEFI boots faster and can use GPT, which is one of the main advantages. Other advantages being the interface which looks nice (you'll notice and old BIOS is just a blue screen with some text and not that many options), but also has expanded functionality.

MBR can be used on both BIOS and UEFI, but GPT can only be used on UEFI.

It seems your computer (or rather, your UEFI configuration!) only accepts GPT - that's fine. You could probably change some settings inside your UEFI to support MBR as well.

With installation USBs, you have to select the right partition from the start - you cannot install a MBR boot partition from an USB that has been formatted to GPT. Windows installation program then takes care to format the disks appropriately.